# Modification of the Eight queens puzzle program in c++

Tags: c++

So the eight queens puzzle has been solved many times, but I haven't seen one a program for it in c++ that allows the user to input a row to start the search from.

The assignment directions:  Revise this program such that the
main() does not have to start from only the row 0. Instead the program will read the start row
number (in rage of 0 – 7) from the keyboard. Make appropriate revision of four functions in the
original program such that it could still print out a viable placement starting from specified row.

This is code for the original program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int NUMBER_OF_QUEENS = 8; // Constant: eight queens
int queens[NUMBER_OF_QUEENS];
// Check whether a queen can be placed at row i and column j
bool isValid(int row, int column)
{
 for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
 if (queens[row - i] == column // Check column
 || queens[row - i] == column - i // Check upper left diagonal
 || queens[row - i] == column + i) // Check upper right diagonal
 return false; // There is a conflict
 return true; // No conflict
}
// Display the chessboard with eight queens
void printResult()
{
 cout << "\n---------------------------------\n";
 for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; row++)
 {
 for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
 printf(column == queens[row] ? "| Q " : "| ");
 cout << "|\n---------------------------------\n";
 }
}
// Search to place a queen at the specified row
bool search(int row)
{
 if (row == NUMBER_OF_QUEENS) // Stopping condition
 return true; // A solution found to place 8 queens in 8 rows
 for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
 {
 queens[row] = column; // Place a queen at (row, column)
 if (isValid(row, column) && search(row + 1))
 return true; // Found, thus return true to exit for loop
 }
 // No solution for a queen placed at any column of this row
 return false;
}
int main()
{
 search(0); // Start search from row 0. Note row indices are 0 to 7
 printResult(); // Display result
 return 0;
}
```

And here is the code I've written so far which does not run correctly and I've modified only slightly. I'm not entirely sure how to go about this problem but main() is exactly as it should be for the modification.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int NUMBER_OF_QUEENS = 8; // Constant: eight queens
int queens[NUMBER_OF_QUEENS];
// Check whether a queen can be placed at row i and column j
bool isValid(int row, int column)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++)
        if (queens[row - i] == column // Check column
            || queens[row - i] == column - i // Check upper left diagonal
            || queens[row - i] == column + i) // Check upper right diagonal
            return false; // There is a conflict
    return true; // No conflict
}
// Display the chessboard with eight queens
void printResult(int row)
{
    cout << "\n---------------------------------\n";
    for (row; row < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
            printf(column == queens[row] ? "| Q " : "| ");
        cout << "|\n---------------------------------\n";
    }
}
// Search to place a queen at the specified row
bool search(int row)
{
    if (row == NUMBER_OF_QUEENS) // Stopping condition
        return true; // A solution found to place 8 queens in 8 rows
    for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
    {
        queens[row] = column; // Place a queen at (row, column)
        if (isValid(row, column) && search(row + 1))
            return true; // Found, thus return true to exit for loop
        }
        // No solution for a queen placed at any column of this row
        return false;
    }
    int main()
    {
        int inputRow;
        cout << "Enter the row to search from:" << endl;
        cin >> inputRow;
        search(inputRow); // Start search from row 0. Note row indices are 0         to 7
    printResult(inputRow); // Display result
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm very new to programming and the site, as I started on java last year and c++ only a month and a half ago, so I'm sorry if I formatted this incorrectly or this wasn't phrased very well, but I'm quite stumped by this problem and really do appreciate any time spend by the programmers on this site and any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your implementation.

If you want to generalize the algorithm, you can let the user choose the position (row and column) of the first queen.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int NUMBER_OF_QUEENS = 8; // Constant: eight queens
int queens[NUMBER_OF_QUEENS];

bool isValid(int row, int column);
bool search(int q);
                                    // Display the chessboard with the queens
void printResult()
{
    cout << "\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n";
    for ( int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++)
            printf(column == queens[row] ? "| Q " : "|   ");
        cout << "|\n+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int iRow, iColumn;

    cout << "Please, enter the row and the column of the cell where you want to put the first Queen into." << endl;
    cout << "Input values must be in the range 0 - " << NUMBER_OF_QUEENS << ". Enter a letter to stop." << endl;        
    while (cin >> iRow && cin >> iColumn) {
        if ( iRow < 0 || iRow > NUMBER_OF_QUEENS - 1
             || iColumn < 0 || iColumn > NUMBER_OF_QUEENS - 1 ) continue;

        for ( int k = 0; k < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; k++) queens[k] = - NUMBER_OF_QUEENS;
        queens[iRow] = iColumn;             // initialize the array with significant values. Ugly, I know.

        if ( !search(0) )                   // Start the search
            cerr << "Error: Unable to find a solution!\n";      
        printResult();                  // Display result
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Your check function doesn't do a complete scan, I prefer this:

```
// Check whether a queen can be placed at row i and column j
bool isValid(int row, int column)
{
    int d1 = column - row;
    int d2 = column + row;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; i++) {
        if ( queens[i] == column                // Check column
            || queens [i] == d1                 // Check diagonals
            || queens [i] == d2 )
                return false; // There is a conflict
       d1++;
       d2--;
    }
   return true; // No conflict
}
```

But the main problem is the search function, which has to try a possible position and reject it if it is not valid:

```
// Search to place a queen at the specified row
bool search(int q)
{
    if (q >= NUMBER_OF_QUEENS)                          // Stopping condition, all rows visited
        return true;                                    // A solution found to place 8 queens in 8 rows
    if ( queens[q] != -NUMBER_OF_QUEENS )               // Skip the row if a queen is already there
        return search(q+1);                 
    else {

        for (int column = 0; column < NUMBER_OF_QUEENS; column++) {
            if (isValid(q, column)) {                   // First check, then
                queens[q] = column;                     // place a queen at (row, column)
                if ( search(q + 1) )  return true;      // Found, thus return true to exit for loop
                else queens[q] = - NUMBER_OF_QUEENS;    // Reject the wrong position
            }
        }
    }
        // No solution for a queen placed at any column of this row
    return false;
}
```

Now you can test the program. For example if you enter `2 5` the output is:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | Q |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | Q |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   | Q |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | Q |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   | Q |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| Q |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   | Q |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   | Q |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely errors in the changes you made

In printResult, you added a 'row' parameter; but, it doesn't actually get used because the for statement declares another variable 'row' that overshadows it.

If you want more details, you are going to have to describe more about what the problem you are seeing is (compiler error, runtime error, wrong output, etc.)

Also, Note that `isValid(int row, int column)` looks at the contents of `queens[row - i]` to make that decision.  Your approach will skip the initial rows and thus isValid will not have the information it needs to make a correct decision.  I suggest that must complete the search through all the rows the just print the one row, you need .

Comment: I changed the for loop so that I wasn't instantiating another "row" variable. The problem my edited version has is that I'm not getting anywhere near the right output. The queens are printed on the same row most of the time.

Comment: http://ultraimg.com/image/IRV3 is the output for when the search begins on row four. The program completely ignored the first four rows, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix that.

Comment: @Yahazu I edited the answer to describe what I believe is breaking the algorithm.